# PHP: Render code as *min (no spaces, tabs or enters) before returning to user

Tags: php, request, response, min

Is it possible to generate a min version of the returned request, (like jquery.min)
Sometimes I find that the final HTML generated from my PHP script is very long and I am trying to optimize the load weight of my site as much as possible.

I know I have to take care of other things like external files, images, etc. But this will be one little extra thing that will slightly improve the amount of data to transfer back to the user when opening a page.

If my page weighs 50k instead of 185k and it is opened 6000 times a day (very conservative), I am saving 0.8 GB of data transfer daily!!! :)

Basically I am thinking of executing some kind of code at the enb of the file that will read the output before returning a response and remove unnecessary characters. (look at microsoft.com as an example)

ex:

Instead of:

```
<div>
    <h1>My Title</h1>
</div>
```

Generate:

```
<div><h1>My Title</h1></div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe adding a gzip with `ob_start("ob_gzhandler");` or `ini_set("zlib.output_compression", "On");` might help?

Comment: I still want to return the same type of file, but minimized, I added an example, thanks.

Comment: how are you serving the file/ generating the output? that would be helpful to know to give you a solution.

Comment: When you open on your browser www.mystite.com/index.php the server runs whatever php code there is on the file index.php and returns to you the generated HTML. I want to return a min version of the HTML output. Thanks